A deduction in Riemannian Geometry
I'm learning Riemannian Geometry recently. When I reached at first variation formula of arc length, I saw the notation:
\begin{equation}
D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\gamma'=D_{\gamma'}\gamma'
\end{equation}
where $\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow M$ is a smooth curve.
I'm wondering how the equation holds.Any some explanations?

Could you state your question in more detail? Are you asking why $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \gamma'$$
